# Is there any efficient way to store streaming data from different stock exchanges in Python besides Parquet files while using CCXT library?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ccxt, pyspark-pandas

**What is the best way to store streaming data from different stock exchanges in order to minimise data weight?**

Right now I'm using CCXT library on Python and in order to get current order book information and save in into Parquet type file using code below:

But everytime I save data my parquet file getting bigger and bigger and opening it everytime in order to save data using to_parquet() function is making my code speed go slower. Because of it as a time goes by I get a huge time lags in my dataframe.

Maybe you can recommend some different ways to store such type of data?

```
import ccxt.pro
import asyncio
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

async def watch_book(exchange, ticker):
    last = None
    limits = {'Binance': 1000,
              'Huobi': 150}
    columns = ['bids_price', 'bids_value', 'asks_price', 'asks_value', 'time']
    while True:
        try:
            bids, asks = {}, {}
            orderbook = await exchange.watch_order_book(ticker)
            now = datetime.datetime.now()

            for b in orderbook['bids']:
                bids[str(float(b[0]))] = float(b[1])
            for a in orderbook['asks']:
                asks[str(float(a[0]))] = float(a[1])

            x = np.empty(limits[exchange.name])
            x.fill(orderbook['timestamp'])
            data_table = pd.DataFrame([bids.keys(), bids.values(), asks.keys(), asks.values(), x], index=columns).T.dropna(axis=1, how='all').replace({None: np.nan}).fillna(0).astype(float).set_index('time')
            
            if os.path.exists(f'{exchange.name}_snap.parquet.gzip'):
                data_table.to_parquet(f'{exchange.name}_snap.parquet.gzip', engine='fastparquet', append=True,
                                      compression='gzip')
            else:
                data_table.to_parquet(f'{exchange.name}_snap.parquet.gzip', engine='fastparquet', compression='gzip')

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'{exchange.name} failed {type(e)} {e}')


async def main():
    exchange_ids = ['binance']
    exchanges = [getattr(ccxt.pro, exchange_id)() for exchange_id in exchange_ids]
    try:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait({watch_book(exchange, 'BTC/USDT') for exchange in exchanges}, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
        for completed in done:
            # trigger the exception here
            completed.result()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'closing all exchanges because of exception {type(e)} {e}')
        await asyncio.gather(*[exchange.close() for exchange in exchanges])


asyncio.run(main())
```

I have tried using parquet data type file to store my data

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to help debug exactly which lines in your code is slowing down. This will at least tell you what the bottleneck is.

I suspect the bottleneck is in the Parquet or Gzip compression. If this is the case, a simple solution would be to split up into multiple files. Maybe every hour, create a new parquet file with the newest streamed data.

This way, the size of the data on the disk is the same, but you don't have to decompress/append to/re-compress a massive file every time.